# Geofire and FirebaseUI with Upgraded Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire, firebaseui

I use Geofire and FirebaseUI in my app.

In the documentation for how to upgrade to the new Firebase SDK, it says I need Geofire 1.2.x or beyond. However, this is not yet available in cocoapods. When will it be available?

Also, will I need to upgrade Firebase UI? How should I do that? It seems like a lot of the code for authentication is now outdated, so it would make sense that FirebaseUI would need to be upgraded.

**Update**

With FirebaseUI, I get this output in Terminal:

```
- `Firebase (~> 3.2)` required by `Podfile`
- `Firebase (~> 2.2)` required by `FirebaseUI (0.3.2)`
```

And with Geofire, I get this output in Terminal:

```
[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `GeoFire (~> 1.2)` required by `Podfile`
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got it spot on with Firebase update requirements for GeoFire, but for a "when"... well, as posted by David East of Firebase on GeoFire's github repo:

"Best estimate I can give you is that we will update GeoFire for iOS in the coming days to weeks. We've got a lot of open source libraries to update across a handful of languages, so it takes us time to make it all happen. Pull requests are always welcome if you want to give it a shot yourself!"

For now, if you're actively using GeoFire, I suggest just keeping Firebase at 2.5.1 and GeoFire at 1.1.3 and continue working until updates are pushed out. As for Firebase UI, it's different but documented here:

https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-ios-swift/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#4

Hope this cleared things up. I was pretty frustrated with it as well.